# HTML In Page reverting to original HTML after innerHTML changed with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

Maybe this is an incompatibility between using an HTML form and AJAX, but I've used these methods separately no problem.  I'm trying to set the input from a form field to a JS variable, execute AJAX to confirm the password on the client side in a php script, then on success change the html on the original page.  the AJAX call works fine, but after it switches the HTML in my div, the page reverts back to it's original state immediately after (i.e. it shows the form again and not the resulting HTML from the function).

Is this an issue where I can't use this type of form and then remain in the same page without it refreshing?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var pw;
    var ptest;

    function pass() {
        pw = document.getElementById("pwd").value;

        alert(pw);
        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { password : pw
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {

                document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = data;
            },
            error: function () { document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = 'fail'; }
        });
                alert("xx");
    }
</script>

<html>
<body>

<br><br>
<div id="stuff"> 
<form onsubmit="pass()" autocomplete="off">
    <label>Password: <input type="password" id="pwd"></label><br><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The form reloads with no other action. the JS changes the html properly on success of the ajax with the html retrieved from my php file, it flashes to the new html and then reloads with the original form

Comment: clicking on a submit button in a form with no action effectively reloads the page - as you have no action, why do you even need a form?

Comment: My guess is t hat you are calling ajax with your suibmt function then submitting the form anyway. Change your button to a regular button that calls ajax

Comment: yeah I guess it's reloading with no action command.  thanks for the explanation guys

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the event and prevent the default action. A form submission triggers a browser reload.

`function pass(e){
         e.preventDefault();
}`

Comment: as `pass` function is called from `onsubmit="pass()"` - it wont get the event argument

Comment: quite right and good catch. The author will need to use something to the effect of `$('form').submit(pass);`

Comment: ... and remove the `onsubmit="pass()"` in the markup

Answer (score 2):

remove the form, change the sumbit input to a regular type="button" input and profit

```
<html>
<body>

<br><br>
<div id="stuff"> 
    <label>Password: <input type="password" id="pwd"></label><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="pass()" value="submit"/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> For the sake of an alternative - useful for more complex forms (maybe). This uses e.preventDefault - as first suggested by @TateThurston in his answer

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var pw;
            var ptest;

            function pass(e) {
                // stop the submission in it's tracks
                e.preventDefault();
                pw = document.getElementById("pwd").value;

                $.ajax({
                    url: "login.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { password : pw },
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function (data) {
                        document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = data;
                    },
                    error: function () { 
                        document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = 'fail'; 
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br><br>
        <div id="stuff"> 
            <form id="myform" autocomplete="off">
                <label>Password: <input type="password" id="pwd"></label><br><br>
                <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            // this code needs to appear AFTER the form, so getElementById should work. 
            // A better solution is to wait for DOMContentLoaded event on document to do such event bindings
            // attach submit event listener to the form (added id to form to make this trivial)
            document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', pass);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

P.S. I noticed that you load jQuery but use document.getElementById instead of jQuery functions - I've written the the code above without jQuery as well

Comment: That did the trick, definitely unnecessary having the form there. Appreciate the help

Comment: don't get me wrong, form can be used in a more complex example - the presence of the form element can make things simple - @TateThurston's answer, while has one slight flaw, does point to an alternative way of dealing with having a form that you want to prevent the default submit action on. Just for such a simple "form", it's probably far easier to do without the form element and the workarounds needed

Answer (score 0):

This is because when your form submits, your page automatically reloads. And the default behavior of  is to submit the current form even if Javascript events are attached to it  This happened to me a long time ago too so try this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var pw;
    var ptest;

    function pass() {
        pw = document.getElementById("pwd").value;

        alert(pw);
        $.ajax({
            url: "login.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { password : pw
            },
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {

                document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = data;
            },
            error: function () { document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML = 'fail'; }
        });
    }
</script>

<html>
<body>

<br><br>
<div id="stuff"> 
<form autocomplete="off">
    <label>Password: <input type="password" id="pwd"></label><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick = "pass()" />
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The trick is to change the  to  and change the call to pass() from onsubmit to onclick

Answer (score -1):

The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.
Use this code:

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); pass();" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: well, damn .. event is not undefined! - learning new things is what keeps me coming back